# Kindle - display images in html

Tags: html, image, email, kindle

I understand this might not be the best place to ask this question...

I have an application that's sending important html documents to my Kindle. They are displayed all right, but all referenced resources (css, images etc) are not there.

I don't really care about absent css, but having images is crucial for me. Even though sometimes they are absolutely referenced, they are not displayed.

I tried to send a zipped archive with the html file and all images it references, but Kindle interpreted it as separate documents instead.

P.S. I'm sending the documents via Amazon's free @free.kindle.com e-mail.

Comment: how are they absolutely referenced? do you have an example?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, however... I needed to convert some html files with images to .mobi (kindle internal format).  I was using Calibre (great software!) for this.  Turned out, kindle was only displaying images correctly if they were residing in the same physical directory as the html and referenced using relative path (i.e. no path, just the name).  Otherwise, even in the resulting .mobi files, the images were not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [KindleGen utility](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000234621) to generate from your .html to .mobi to preserve images, css and use things like cover image, table of contents etc.

When you have your .html file and related image resources you have to create (generate) .opf file (generally it is just xml file describing your book resources). KindleGen has 
included example of Kindle User guide in .html with related .opf

After that just use kindlegen with your .opf file from shell to create .mobi file which you can email after to your kindle email adress.

Answer (score 0):

When you send only a zip to the Kindle it will separate everything in this document.

You need to convert this zip into a mobi file then the Kindle know this is one document.
For that task you can use Calibre or any other ebook converter. Every image has to be in the root-directory and referenced via a relative path.

Sample:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Logo</h1>
<img src='blabla.png'/>
</div>
```